# using google custom search for images that are free to use or share

Tags: google-custom-search

I am trying to use the Google Custom Search to search for image. I want to filter results from the custom search engine by licencing. Are there any settings to find creative commons images? I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way indeed, please refer to [this guide](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/devguide#setRestriction).